# extract string component to store as hash map key within function, pattern matcher?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have data stored in files at paths such as:

```
/home/yamada/data/train/atheism/file_name.txt
```

I use this data to populate a hash map, storing the origin of the data and its contents as follows.

```
/home/yamada/data/test/sports/t.s_1.txt, [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
/home/yamada/data/test/politics/t.p_0.txt, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
/home/yamada/data/test/atheism/t.a_0.txt, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
/home/yamada/data/test/science/t.s_0.txt, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

However, I want only to store the path to the point of the directory, not the specific file, like so:

```
/home/yamada/data/train/atheism
```

The following regex command is capable of extracting the component I'm interested in according to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sP8gE2/1):

```
(home\/yamada\/data\/train\/atheism)
```

How could I use the java pattern matcher to ensure that only the string mentioned earlier, the path up to and including the directory, but not the file name, is saved to the hash map?

Is the pattern matcher the best choice for this operation?

Below is the method that populates the hash map.

```
public static void perceptron_data_struc_generateur(Set<String> GLOBO_DICT, 
                                                        Map<File, ArrayList<String> > fileDict,
                                                        Map<File, int[] > perceptron_input)
    {
        //create a new entry in the array list 'perceptron_input'
        //with the key as the file name from fileDict
            //create a new array which is the length of GLOBO_DICT
            //iterate through the indicies of GLOBO_DICT
                //for all words in globo dict, if that word appears in fileDict,
                //increment the perceptron_input index that corresponds to that
                //word in GLOBO_DICT by the number of times that word appears in fileDict

        //so i can get the index later
        List<String> GLOBO_DICT_list = new ArrayList<>(GLOBO_DICT);

        for (Map.Entry<File, ArrayList<String>> entry : fileDict.entrySet()) 
        {
            int[] cross_czech = new int[GLOBO_DICT_list.size()];
            //initialize to zero
            Arrays.fill(cross_czech, 0);

            for (String s : GLOBO_DICT_list)
            {

                for(String st : entry.getValue()) 
                {
                    if( st.equals(s) )
                    {
                        cross_czech[ GLOBO_DICT_list.indexOf( s ) ] = cross_czech[ GLOBO_DICT_list.indexOf( s ) ] +1;
                    }
                }
            }
            perceptron_input.put( entry.getKey() , cross_czech);    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a bit simpler than that:

```
String dir = filename.replaceAll("/[^/]*$", "");
```

Comment: this would truncate the filename?

Comment: Isn't that what you meant? The dir name?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to find only parts which ends with `/` (file name will not have it). In that case

```
(\w+/)+
```

[should do the trick](https://regex101.com/r/sP8gE2/2) (BTW we don't escape `/` in Java's regex)

---

But if your data is always in form `path/to/file` and you only want to extract `path/to` then you don't need regex, you can use File class and its `getParent` method like

```
String data = new File("/home/yamada/data/train/atheism/file_name.txt").getParent();
System.out.println(data);
```

This will return `\home\yamada\data\train\atheism` so you will have `/` instead of `\`, but this shouldn't be a problem if you want to use this data in Java (`File` accepts both separators).

Comment: maybe I can use this in conjunction with the code from @Bohemian

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō Bohemians solution will create new String with removed entire content after last `/`. You could try to combine my solution with it but I don't think it is necessary. Anyway I updated my answer with non-regex solution which seems easier than previous one.

Comment: Glad you like it. Bohemian solution is also very easy if you know regex. It will try to find and remove substring which starts with `/` and until end of string (`$`) will have only non `/` characters (`[^/]`*).